# w520 sleep freeze

Tags: windows-7, freeze, sleep

This laptop is driving me crazy.
Sometimes when I instruct it to go to sleep (by closing the lid or pressing hotkey on keyboard).
It either doesn't respond to the commandThe screen goes black but it never goes to sleep, the battery icon stays on I can hear the fan but the sleep icon never turns on. And in that stage I never have a way to get the screen to turn on again and I have to hard reboot.

What can cause sleep feature glitches? It is happening on a consistent basis and is unusable.

Other details of my configuration:
- I use a docking station once in a while
- I use truecrypt to mount containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good starting point is to try running `powercfg -energy` from an elevated command prompt.  The report generated may pinpoint an issue.  USUALLY, this sort of behavior is caused by a bad device driver (or a piece of hardware itself) or system service, but picking through them one by one can be awfully time consuming if there's no pattern to what causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that was sooo cool to see that. I have close to a fresh install and a ton of things that it flagged on the desktop.  That tool makes seeing what windows is seeing very easy.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty neat tool, I like it a lot.  Did it point you at anything obvious?

Comment: nothing is obvious to me :-) it was layers of stuff. looking at it closer it did say that it saw no "problems or errors" even though it pointed out that many things were not set to power down.

Comment: That's good; I'd expect a new machine not to complain. We'll see what the original poster has to say, though... :)